# Ffmpeg: color related commands

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, colors

I use hlae+ffmpeg for recording and for parameters of recording i set: `-c:v ffv1 -pix_fmt gbrap16le -coder -2 -g 1 -threads 4 -context 1 -slices 30 -slicecrc 1 -level 3 -fps_mode passthrough -sws_flags +full_chroma_inp+full_chroma_int+accurate_rnd+bitexact out.mov`

The question is: do I really need to use `-sws_flags +full_chroma_inp+full_chroma_int+accurate_rnd+bitexact` since i don't convert anything but record?

Comment: Welcome Skyfall. Please note that Superuser, being a Question and Answer site, needs a single specific question per post, so that a single specific answer can be given. Multiple posts are OK, but please make each only have a single question accompanied by enough information that we can clearly understand what you are asking. You can EDIT your post to improve it and to focus it on a single question.